# How to load Object Oriented variable value in Yii PHP using <<<HTMLDOC .... HTMLDOC format

Tags: php, yii

i want to use the following code

```
$mail->Body = <<<HTMLDOC
$this->model->firstname . $this->model->lastname,
today is your lucky day !
your desired product has reached your desired price !
HTMLDOC;
```

but i get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in ...

$this->model->firstname has a value, i checked

Comment: Need to see more code, Is this code within a class method?

Comment: yes, it is in a class; btw, i managed to do it myself; i just used $user_first_name = $this->model_user->firstname; ouside the special format, and in the special format i used $user_first_name; it works just fine;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try writing the heredoc text like so:

```
$mail->Body = <<<HTMLDOC
{$this->model->firstname} {$this->model->lastname},
today is your lucky day !
your desired product has reached your desired price !
HTMLDOC;
```

Either that or you can use views for mail messages (some extensions allow this).